# Static IP Address and proxy with Heroku with Proximo and nginx

Tags: heroku, nginx, proxy, proximo

I have a static IP address setup on Heroku with Proxmio. And I want to use the [Proximo proxy](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/proximo#using-the-proximo-http-proxy) to proxy all requests using nginx (also on the same heroku instance).

Here's what I have as the nginx config for proxying the Proxmio requests:

```
  location <%= ENV["API_PREFIX_PATH"] || "/api/" %> {
    proxy_pass <%= ENV["API_URL"] %>;
    proxy_set_header Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_set_header Proxy-Authorization "Basic ZDA3YadmdmglN5Q21T24Y4gt4TE13S03bDI2dzVmdmUzsjQ=";
    proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
    proxy_redirect off;
    <% if ENV["NGINX_DEBUG"] %>add_header Ember-Cli-Proxy on;<% end %>
  }
```

Note the ENV variables are set on heroku.

This seems close to correct, but the proxy authentication doesn't seem to be working because requests come back as [407](https://httpstatuses.com/407)s.

Is something off with the way I'm setting the proxy auth?

Comment: you better not post your auth key

Comment: @Ixknivlk the one I posted is not real.